# Can't access RoleManager's extension method RoleExist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am not sure whats up here. I created a simple custom RoleManager like this.

```
namespace Webservices.Infrastructure.Identity
{
public class PocketDoctorRoleManager : RoleManager<PocketDoctorRole>
{
    public PocketDoctorRoleManager(RoleStore<PocketDoctorRole> store) : base(store) {

    }
    public static PocketDoctorRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<PocketDoctorRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {

        return new PocketDoctorRoleManager(new RoleStore<PocketDoctorRole>(context.Get<PocketDoctorIdentityDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

}

and am trying to access the RoleExists extension method in the IdentityDbInitalization class like this.

```
namespace Webservices.Infrastructure.Identity
{
public class PocketDoctorIdentityDbInitializer :    CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PocketDoctorIdentityDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(PocketDoctorIdentityDbContext context)
    {
        PocketDoctorRoleManager roleMgr =
        new PocketDoctorRoleManager(new RoleStore<PocketDoctorRole>(context));

        string roleNameAdmin = "Administrators";
        string userNameAdmin = "admin@porders.com";
        string passwordAdmin = "secret";
        string emailAdmin = "admin@porders.com";

        roleMgr.RoleExist// this isn't found
        base.Seed(context);
    }

}
```

}

What could be the possible reason here ? . As you can see I have all the classes in one namespace too , hence I should have been able to see the extension methods for RoleManager.

Comment: Add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManagerExtensions;`

Comment: While your suggestion didn't exactly work , it did lead me to the proper solution . 

I actually didn't use Micros.aspnet.identity in the file , rather had used mic.aspnet.identity.entityframework.

You made me realize the location of the RoleManagerExtensions.